# Control webcam from C#

Tags: c#, webcam, device

I have a Creative Life CAM Optia AF webcam, the software included in the package is able to control the camera in different ways, like set autofocus to auto or manual, and a bunch of gamma and brightness settings.

I'm capturing the feed with the AForge Computer vision library, and it's working great.
But i would like to be able to set the manual focus from inside my application.

Ive been searching for a tutorial, but come up empty handed.
Can i somehow either disassemble the included software, or is there some way to fetch the traffic / instructions being sent to the device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of application is it? .Net and you're in luck, native would be harder.

Comment: It is not a .net application. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If the license agreement that comes with the software allows you to disassemble it, you can do so with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) (assuming that it's a .NET application).

Comment: The application is not a .net app.

Answer (score 0):

[How to programatically disable the auto-focus of a webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717780/how-to-programatically-disable-the-auto-focus-of-a-webcam)

I think i found a way to do this. But i have never written any C++, that is C++ right?

Thanks :)