# Disable Auto Focus in Video Input Library or OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I am using Video Input library to get frames from a webcam. I want to set FOCUS of this camera in C code.

Camera has **AUTO FOCUS** enabled. Isn't there a way to **disable autofocus and set a specific focus value**.

Regards,
Saleh...

Comment: I know i can set focus in Video Input Library using following code;
setVideoSettingCamera(int deviceID, long Property, long lValue, long Flags = NULL, bool useDefaultValue = false);

But it's not working.

Comment: The answer might be platform dependent. What OS/hardware are you using?

Comment: windows... you can consider any of these: 7 64/32 or windows xp 32 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1718009/7531 It requires you use directshow, but this should be possible.

Otherwise, have you looked at the [OpenCV documentation for CameraCapture](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture). the section concerning camera parameters shows how --in general- you control camera parameters, a quick look in `videoinput.h` should show you the parameters for autofocus.
[This is a complete example](https://redkiing.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/capture-video-with-opencv-and-videoinput-windows-only/) of setting autofocus this way.

[`IAMCameraControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389145%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the windows interface for controlling parameters.

Note that depending on the webcam you use, and/or the specific firmware version it might not be possible to control focus / autofocus at all.

Comment: oh yes. I can disable it via the settings windows using mouse cursor in VideoInput Library. It means Camera drivers have support for enabling n disabling AutoFocus. but the problem is that its not configurable via coding. You've mentioned OpenCV's implementation for camera capture. In this implementation no property (Focus,Zoom,Brightness etc) is working. :(

Comment: @ saleh - How did you fix your problem?

Comment: @Saleh, Please mention that how you fix the problem. thanks

Answer (score 15):

If you use the OpenCV 3.1.0-dev version and Python 2.7.5, the following code snipped should help you ;)

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) # my webcam
cap.set(3, 1280) # set the resolution
cap.set(4, 720)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0) # turn the autofocus off
```

With my Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 is works fine. There are many other cool control functions inside cv2, like `cv2.CAP_PROP_BRITHNESS` or `cv2.CAP_PROP_CONTRAST`. 
Check out what the auto-complete is showing you ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have searched for this problems for couples of days and tried videoinput library and directshow. 
If you just want to set up the camera parameters for once (manually) inside opencv, the easiest way I found is:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 1);
```

it will pop out a window for you to set the parameters. enough to disable autofocus.

The inconvenience of this method is that if you want to control the focal length by program, it cannot do that.

Comment: For newer versions you can use cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 1)

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are looking for is camera and driver specific. [The OpenCV camera property controls](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) provide only very rudimentary parameters.
There is no generic way to make that call through OpenCV.

To do it, not through OpenCV, you can do do one of the following:

- Manually access the driver's capture properties as [@user3211236 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24164870/135862): `cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_SETTINGS, 1);`
- Programatically, via OS/driver specific API as [@jillesdewit suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9208589/135862).