# OpenCv Issue of Image Subtraction?

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction

i am trying to subtract 2 image using the function cvAbsDiff(img1, img2, dest);
it working but sometimes when i bring my hand before my head or body the hand is not clear and background comes into picture... the background image(head) overlays my foreground.(hand)..

it works correctly on plain surfaces i.e when the background is even like a wall.

please check out my image...so that you can better understand my problem...!!!!

http://www.2shared.com/photo/hJghiq4b/bg_overlays_foreground.html

if you have any solution/hint please help me.......

Answer (score 1):

Putting in the relevant code would help. Also knowing what you're actually trying to achieve.

Which two images are you subtracting? I've done subtracting subsequent images (so, images taken with a delay of a fraction of a second), and the background subtraction generally results in the edges of moving objects, for example the edges of a hand, and not the entire silhouette of a hand. I'm guessing you're taking the difference of the current frame and a static startup frame. It's possible that parts aren't different enough (skin+skin).

I've got some computer problems tonight, I'll test it out tomorrow (pls put up at least the steps you actually carry thorough though) and let you know.

---

I'm still not sure what your ultimate goal is, although I'm guessing you want to do some gesture-recognition (since you have a vector called "fingers").
As Manpreet said, your biggest problem is robustness, and that is from the subjects having similar color.

I reproduced your image by having my face in the static comparison image, then moving it. If I started with only background, it was already much more robust and in anycase didn't display any "overlaying".

Quick fix is, make sure to have a clean subject-free static image.
Otherwise, you'll want to have dynamic comparison image, simplest would be comparing frame_n with frame_n-1. This will generally give you just the moving edges though, so if you want the entire silhouette you can either:

1) Use a different segmenting algorithm (what I recommend. Background subtraction is fast and you can use it to determine a much smaller ROI in which to search, and then use a different algorithm for more robust segmentation.)

2) Try to make a compromise between the static and dynamic comparison image, for example as an average of the past 10 frames or something like that. I don't know how well this works, but would be quite simple to implement, worth a try :).

Also, try with CV_THRESH_OTSU instead of 30 for your threshold value, see if you like that better.

Also, I noticed often the output flares (regions which haven't changed switch from black to white). Checking with the live stream, I'm quite certain it because of the webcam autofocusing/adjusting white balance etc.. If you're getting that too, turning off the autofocus etc. should help (which btw isn't done through openCV but depends on the camera. Possibly check this: [How to programatically disable the auto-focus of a webcam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717780/how-to-programatically-disable-the-auto-focus-of-a-webcam))

Comment: you are right.. i do take a static image and then try to subtract it from webcam query image.... this is my code...

Comment: you are right.. i do take a static image and then try to subtract it from webcam query image... this is the link to my code....please help.         http://www.2shared.com/document/0LaAP-mQ/subtraction.html

Comment: I added an answer more specific to your code. Hope this helps, depends a bit on what you really want to achieve though.
On a side note, unless you have specific reasons not to, I would recommend adopting the newer C++ standards of openCV, namely using Mat for your images.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code . Background subtraction is not a preffered way for motion detection or silhoutte detection because its not very robust.The problem is coming because both the background and the foreground are similar in colour at many regions which on subtractions pushes the foreground to back . You might try using
- optical flow for motion detection 
- If your task is just detecting silhoutte or hand try training a HOG classifier over it

In case you do not want to try a new approach . You may try around playing with the threshold value(in your case 30).So when you subtract similar colour image there difference is less than 30 . And later you threshold with 30 so it just blacks out. Also you may try HSV or some other colourspace as well .

Comment: but if it is because of what you said i.e background and foreground being the same colour then it should just subtract it. isn't? is there any method to bring foreground in front of background ?